# React Checkbox default value to true

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am working with backend value whos initial value comes to the UI as false or null.
if the value is false or null, then my checkbox needs to be checked, and if the backend value comes in as true, then my checkbox needs to be unchecked. Using, Material UI checkbox

link to codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/controlledcheckbox-material-demo-forked-3rv5z5?file=/demo.js

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Checkbox from '@mui/material/Checkbox';

export default function ControlledCheckbox() {
  const [checked, setChecked] = React.useState(false);

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setChecked(event.target.checked);
  };

  console.log('checked: ', checked);
  return (
    <Checkbox
      checked={checked === false ? true : checked}
      onChange={handleChange}
      inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'controlled' }}
    />
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can just use

```
checked = {checked}.
```

refer: https://codesandbox.io/s/controlledcheckbox-material-demo-forked-igg9h2

Comment: No, the state needs to be false

Comment: set checked as false initially, it would be unchecked initially. then use setChecked on useEffect to set based on the backend!

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is begin with a React useEffect to do a backend query to get the current state of the checkbox. Then, if it turns out to be true, you can call your state hook and do a setChecked(true) that will automatically change the state to true. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Checkbox` without controller you can use `defaultChecked={true}` if you are using the Checkbox with react-hook-form use `defaultValue` instead to set it to true

```js
<Controller
  control={control}
  name='selectItem'
  defaultValue={true} 
  render={({ field: { onChange, value } }) => (
    <FormControlLabel
      control={
        <Checkbox
          checked={value}
          onChange={onChange}
        />
      }
    />
  )}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the code you are looking for:

```
export default function ControlledCheckbox() {
 const [checked, setChecked] = React.useState(false);

 const handleChange = (event) => {
   setChecked(prevCheck => !prevCheck);
 };

 console.log("checked: ", checked);
 return (
   <Checkbox
     checked={!checked}
     onChange={handleChange}
     inputProps={{ "aria-label": "controlled" }}
   />
  );
}
```